# How to delete all records from sqlite3 table after receiving data

Tags: python, sqlite, curl, bottle

I have this bottle file that receives a POST request with a JSON file that stores data in a database. The data is information about devices connected to a WIFI AP. Then with a template that data is printed on a website. How can I delete all the records of the database after being printed? This is a way to check if a device has disconnect.

***bottle.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, run, template, request, SimpleTemplate, Bottle,abort,debug
import sqlite3
import json
import time

@route('/', method='POST')
def index():
    body = request.body.read().decode('utf8') # read directly HTTP input
    get_dict = json.loads(body) # decode json and get native python dict
    maclist = get_dict.get('maclist')
    signallist = get_dict.get('signallist')

    data_list = list(zip(maclist, signallist))
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    try:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO users (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", data_list)
    except Exception as exc:
        c.executemany("REPLACE INTO users (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", data_list)
    conn.commit()

    return "Items added."

@route('/data', method='GET')
def index():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    isEmpty = c.execute('SELECT count(*) from users')

    if (isEmpty != 0):
       c.execute('SELECT * FROM users')


    return template('simple.tpl', rows = c.fetchall())
```

***simple.tpl***

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>MAC address</td>
            <td>Signal</td>
        </tr>
        %for row in rows:
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
            </tr>
        %end
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delete *all* rows? `DELETE FROM tablename`. Delete *some* rows? `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE condition-to-delete-if-true`

Comment: @Shawn The thing is that I wouldn't want the empty table to be printed. I edited my post with a new line in the GET method but it didn't work. So I would like to have the values printed delete them from database and print only the data received.

Comment: You could embed some deletion code at the end of the template file. It might be worth changing your GET function with a. Conditional at the end, so if there is no data, a different blank template is returned.